# Getting a firebase list from an array of indexes

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an index of ordered stories:

```
{
  index: ["storyA", "storyB", "storyC"]
}
```

I want to get the referenced stories and pass it into angularFireCollection

```
{
  index: ["storyA", "storyB", "storyC"],
  stories: {
    "storyA" : {},
    "storyB" : {},
    "storyC" : {},
    "storyD" : {},
    "storyE" : {}
  },
}
```

This is the example from angularfire. This would get all the stories instead of just the ones in the index. How do I get just the ones in the index?

```
app.controller('stories', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'angularFireCollection',
  function($scope, $timeout, angularFireCollection) {
    var url = 'https://example.firebaseio.com/stories';
    $scope.stories = angularFireCollection(url);
  }
]);
```

Comment: would it be acceptable to just filter them?

Comment: Yes, filtering might be your best bet, there's no easy way to only fetch the ones in the index. You could, alternatively, create several instances of angularFire or angularFireCollection, one for each story. Eg: $scope.storyA = angularFireCollection('https://example.firebaseio.com/stories/storyA');

Comment: @lucuma I want to make the indexes work. It's a pretty important part of working with firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harry, check out [FirebaseIndex](https://github.com/Zenovations/FirebaseIndex) for examples on how to use indexes. Almost all the work you do with Firebase is going to involve indexes or normalization of records (matching two sets of records by id), so it's a great topic to study up on.

An index isn't going to work with AngularFire out of the box. However, a little thought and a pull request could be submitted to allow it to work directly with FirebaseIndex (just pass in the FirebaseIndex instead of the url, and in the AngularFire constructor, set `this._fref` to the FirebaseIndex instead of `new Firebase(url)`.

Example:

```
function AngularFire($q, $parse, url) {
  this._q = $q;
  this._parse = $parse;
  this._initial = true;
  this._remoteValue = false;
  this._fRef = typeof(url) === 'string'? new Firebase(url) : url;
}
```

But it's probably not that simple (is anything?). And this would probably be limited to a read-only scope. To make this work in both directions would take quite a bit more planning and leg-work.

Comment: Thanks for FirebaseIndex! I'm just trying to do uni-direction for now. I don't think just setting this._fref is sufficient. Passing in the FirebaseIndex gets an error: `Error: new Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".` Trying to figure it out.

Comment: Harry, you would need to make a modification to AngularFire; the above wasn't meant to be an in-place solution, but rather an idea of how to achieve what you want. See my edits.